# Silhouette Detection using old gl

Tags: opengl

I have been assigned to implement shadows in the project which I am working now. Since we have one light source and our embedded hardware is very old(even not have gpu) we thought stencil buffer implementation of shadow volumes will fit our app best.

As first step I want to implement Silhouette Detection which have been described in the [link](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial39/tutorial39.html). The link is very good but uses geometry shader for dot product calculation of neighboring edges' normal with light direction. Since we still use old fixed pipeline I won't be able to use that part of this example.

I wanted to ask if the best way for me doing all this dot products myself or is there a old opengl trick-function call which may help me?

Comment: [Under the Shade of the Rendering Tree](http://www.darwin3d.com/gamedev/articles/col0200.pdf)

Comment: If your light source and scene is static, calculating the dots yourself is the best way to do it anyway. If your light source or scene is not static, your system may be too slow to calculate the dot product on the fly, but any other approach would require a more sophisticated GPU, which you don't have. AFAIK, opengl does not have any magic non-core GL operation for silhouettes, so you'd have to do it all yourself (but its not that much work, really). To be honest, doing shadows in fixed-pipeline sounds like masochism.